# replace uppercase letters with space in sublime

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext, uppercase

I am trying to process the following two lines in Sublime :

```
2013-12-26T23:24:42Z

test
```

I just want to replace the capital (uppercase) letters with a space. I searched for T|Z, but it selects the lowercase 't' in test in the second line.

Is there a way to select only the uppercase letters? I just want to replace uppercase letters with a space.

Thanks,

Comment: In your search, there should an option for case sensitive search with a symbol **Aa**

Answer (score 6):

You most likely have the case insensitive option selected, because otherwise your regex should work.

Make sure this option is not selected:

[image: SublimeText case sensitive option]

Comment: This was the catch for me! :-)